# White gives checkmate in two moves

Tags: checkmate, problems

```
[FEN "5rk1/2Q2ppp/p7/2P5/1p6/1B5P/Pq2nPP1/3R1K2 w - - 0 1"]
```

White, to move, gives checkmate in two moves. Can anyone find the solution?

Comment: To the downvoters: a comment to explain what's wrong might be useful to educate new users and help retaining them.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Indeed. It's not always obvious. In this case, however, it is obvious. The problem is so trivial as to be a complete waste of time.

Comment: @BrianTowers It seems like a reasonable question for a beginner. Is there a rule that beginner questions are frowned upon here? This doesn't seem much more trivial than, for instance, https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/18848/king-move-to-other-side or https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/16427/instead-of-giving-checkmate-i-gave-stalemate-why .

Comment: @FedericoPoloni I'm not sure that it is reasonable. It's obviously taken from a book, with no attribution. There's no question other than the implied find the move, which any engine can give you immediately.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a question, but more of a social media post

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Perhaps people are downvoting this question because it is both trivial and shows zero research effort. Actually, lots of questions show zero research effort, but this is the one attracting lots of comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is

> 1.Qxf7+.  If Kh8, then Qxf8#.  And if Rxf7, then Rd8# - the rook cannot block because it is pinned by the bishop.